# rigidbody meshes won't move! at all

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, tracking

I've been doing some camera tracking and its all been working fine. then when i tried to add rigid body it wouldn't move

sorry if I'm not being that specific but when i bake to keyframes only two keyframes show up at the beginning and end btw my beginning frame is 908 and end is 1040

Answer (score 1):

sorry it turns out i had to go into the rigid body cache and change its starting and ending frames